# Do I need to post more details in this question?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I posted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1215721/cannot-copy-and-paste-text-from-local-system-to-remote-system-while-using-teamvi) a day ago but it has not received many views and I haven't received any feedback for it.

What can I do to attract more attention towards this question? How can I improve it?

Update:

My problem got resolved after Teamviewer shut down on my remote system and I reopened it. Since then, I have been able to copy and paste text from my local to remote systems and vice-versa.

Comment: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: I eventually ended up answering my own :)
https://superuser.com/questions/1216719/how-can-i-boot-fedora-from-an-iso-file-in-grub-2/1218085#1218085]

Just had to keep plugging at the research!!

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a pretty clear question to me, but since there are only 7 people following the "teamviewer" tag, it indicates the community is not that well "staffed" there :)

In the StackOverflow community there are 20 people following the teamviewer tag, so I would suggest you double post your question there and hope there's more active users that can help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teamviewer

Comment: The author's question would be closed, since it has nothing to do with programming, and thus not within the scope of SO.  Additionally, cross-posting is rarely a good idea, and this case is no exception.

Comment: Ah yes. Indeed.

Comment: There are lots of questions on [SO] that have little to nothing to do with programming, and that do not get closed.  @a_sid shouldn’t just repost (double post) their question on [SO], but, since it’s not getting answered here, there’s nothing to lose by flagging it for moderator attention and asking to have it migrated there.  (You might want to edit it to say “I asked this on [SU] and they couldn’t help me,” even though it will be labeled as “Migrated from Super User.)

Comment: @Scott It would be off-topic on [so] as it has absolutely nothing to do with programming and any migration would likely be rejected.

Comment: The number of people following the tag is not really relevant. I have answered over 2000 questions (including 3 teamviewer) and I don't follow any tags. I look for questions I can answer regardless of their tags.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Have you *looked* at the questions on [SO]?  They get a lot of questions that have little to nothing to do with programming, many of which belong on [SU].  Some get closed, some get migrated, but many stay open and get answered.  Just look at how many [SU] questions get a comment, “This question is answered at [or *is a duplicate of*  ] [SO] question XYZ.” How they would feel about a migration may be a different kettle of fish.  The good news is that the question has an answer now, but the OP hasn’t acknowledged it yet.